# Stacked Column Graph adding to less than 100%

Tags: excel, charts

If I have two percentages e.g. 67% and 80%, I know that I can create a stacked column graph. However, it either adds to 100% or >100%. What I would like to know, is if there is a way to have a column graph with two values, where the 67% is inside the 80% as a different colour and the 80% represents the final 13% on top. This means the total would be 80%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, plot the increment:

[image: Stacked bar chart]

However since I see no programming involved seems Q would be better suited to Super User (where it might soon be migrated).